# Solving $\int_0^{1200}\int_0^{1200-x}\frac{1}{1440000}e^{-x/1200}e^{-y/1200}dy\, \, dx$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How does one solve $\int_0^{1200}\int_0^{1200-x}\frac{1}{1440000}e^{-x/1200}e^{-y/1200}dy\, \, dx$?

The answer, according to Wolfram Alpha is $1-2e^{-1}$, but I continue getting $1-e^{-1}$.

Here's how I tried solving the problem:

After solving for y (itegrated integral), $\int_0^{1200}\frac{1}{1440000}[e^{-x/1200}(-1200)(e^{-y/1200})]_0^{1200-x}dy\, \, dx$. Then, the equation would be simplified into $\frac{-1}{1200}\int_0^{1200}(e^{-1}-e^{-x/1200})\,\, dx$ which would result in $1-e^{-1}$...

Comment: In calculations like this, I would usually write $a=1200$ to avoid confusion with all the numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Let us put $1200=a$ as @DepeHb suggested so we have:

$$\int_0^a\int_0^{a-x}(1/a^2)e^{-x/a}e^{-y/a}dydx=(1/a^2)\int_0^ae^{-x/a}dx\int_0^{a-x}e^{-y/a}dy\\=(1/a^2)\int_0^ae^{-x/a}dx[-ae^{-y/a}]_0^{a-x}=(-1/a)\int_0^ae^{-x/a}(1-e^{x/a-1})dx\\=(-1/a)(ae^{-x/a}+xe^{-1})_0^a=1-2e^{-1}$$

Comment: some question: when doing integration $\int_0^{a-x} e^{-y/a}dy$, I am not sure how this results in $[ae^{-y/a}]^{a-x}_0$. Because I think that should rather be $[-ae^{-y/a}]^{a-x}_0$... If we differentiate the integration result, then it should be $e^{-y/a}$, right?... Placing $u = -y/a$, $du = -1/a \, \, dy$ which seems to bring my result...

Comment: @Inequal: Yes it's a typo. Thanks for noting me that.

Comment: @BabakS.: I agree, nice work +1

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a mistake in the first integration step : only "y" varies from 0 to 1200-x. What Wolfram Alpha gives is correct.

Comment: I think I didn't make that mistake..

Comment: @Inequal. I am sorry, you did not make that mistake. I have been too fast and I apologize. However, you have a mistake when you compute the bound values : you should have -1/1200 (1200/e+1200/e-1200).